# Deploy Spring Boot with MySQL db to Heroku fails during gradle build

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I have an almost ready to deploy app built on my localhost, and my next step of the development is to ready it for deployment. Therefore, I am trying to deploy it on Heroku, but when I try to push the code to Heroku, and it tries to build it, I am getting an error during the process of
`-----> executing ./gradlew build -x check`. When I try to run the same command on my localhost it works perfectly. Therefore, I am unsure about what I am doing wrong and how Heroku needs the app to be set up.

This is the build log for the app:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Spring Boot detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew build -x check
       Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
       ...........10%............20%...........30%............40%............50%...........60%............70%............80%...........90%............100%
       To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
       Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
       
       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
       
       * What went wrong:
       A problem occurred configuring root project 'RnR'.
       > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
          > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.0.
            Required by:
                project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.1.0
             > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1' but:
                 - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                     - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
                     - Other compatible attribute:
                         - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                 - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                     - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                     - Other compatible attributes:
                         - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                         - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                         - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                 - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                     - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
                     - Other compatible attribute:
                         - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                 - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                     - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
                     - Other compatible attribute:
                         - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                 - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                     - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
                     - Other compatible attribute:
                         - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
                 - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                     - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
                     - Other compatible attributes:
                         - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                         - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                         - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
       
       * Try:
       > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
       > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
       > Run with --scan to get full insights.
       
       * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
       
       BUILD FAILED in 8s
 !     ERROR: Failed to run Gradle!
       We're sorry this build is failing. If you can't find the issue in application
       code, please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com
       You can also try reverting to the previous version of the buildpack by running:
       $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle#previous-version
       
       Thanks,
       Heroku
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Gradle app.
 !     Push failed
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

group = 'FamilyFusion'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot Starters
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    // Validation
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.0.6'

    // Thymeleaf Extras
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
    implementation 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:3.2.1'

    // File Upload
    implementation 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.5'

    // Gedcom4j
    implementation 'org.gedcom4j:gedcom4j:4.0.1'

    // JSON
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230618'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // Development Tools
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    // Database Connector
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = 8.40
    maxWarnings = 0
    ignoreFailures = true
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle).configureEach {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        html.required = true
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
####    Database     ####
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roots_and_recipes
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.jpa.database-platform=MySQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

####    SSL     ####
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:FamilyFusionSecurity.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=FamilyFusionSecurity
server.ssl.protocol=TLS

####    Spring Mail     ####
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=****
spring.mail.password=******
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

I know that currently the db is localhost, but I wanted to see if I can first at least build the app on Heroku and then connect it properly to a cloud based db (was planning on using the free version of JawsDB MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin you are applying requires that you run Gradle with at least Java 17.

Locally you run with Java 17 and all is well.

But on Heroku you run with Java 8 which is not supported by the Spring Boot Gradle plugin you use.

You need to configure Heroku to run the Gradle build with Java 17 at least.

As documented at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version, create a file `system.properties` where you set `java.runtime.version=17` for example.

Comment: where do I put the system.properties file? is it the same as the Procfile, or something else?

Comment: If you mean "in the same location as the Procfile", yes, in the root of the project. If you meant "same file", no.